# Can anyone identify the powered exoskeleton in this image?

Tags: object-identification

While cataloging some of my sci-fi assorted images, I found this image that I have in my ‘sci-fi dioramas to-do’ folder. If one considers its appearance, the artwork looks like a sketch of some (nonsense) sort for a sci-fi movie. The only references that I have of this image are the folder name, the file name and the date: Man Machine, exoskeleton and Jan. 13, 2017 respectively but I am almost sure I downloaded from an art of a movie. I am planning to customize it a little bit before use it in order not to infringe authorial rights but I ask if someone could identify it.

[image]

Comment: http://www.monstersinmotion.com/cart/images/26WBA62_General_Grievous.jpg

Comment: Hello General Kenobi.

Comment: @Sava - Hello there; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1GHpnZ6YjiU

Comment: The head and general industrial look reminds me of Cain from Robocop 2, though Cain only had two arms. https://i.pinimg.com/originals/c5/c5/89/c5c589c36ffe2e74223d2e3820df90fa.jpg

Comment: It does not appear to be any of the 75 four-armed comic book characters listed here:  https://comicvine.gamespot.com/profile/tronhammer/lists/four-armed-folk/55376/

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cFwEiG4I-Wg&feature=emb_logo?